# Optimal constant for a functional inequality

Tags: calculus, optimization, calculus-of-variations, integral-inequality, functional-inequalities

I've been working on a problem for a while now and can't seem to arrive at a solution. 
I have to find the optimal constant $C$ that satisfies the inequality:
$$Cu(0)^2 \le \int_0^1u(x)^2\ dx+\int_0^1u'(x)^2\ dx$$
for real valued $u\in C^1(0,1)\cap C([0,1])$.

So far, I've noted that the inequality would hold trivially if $u(0)=0$, so under the assumption that $u(0)\neq0$ I have formulated the Lagrangian:
$$F(x,u(x),u'(x))=\frac{u(x)^2+u'(x)^2}{u(0)^2},$$ which would need to be minimized to find the optimal constant $C$.

I've tried using Euler's equation:
$$F_u-\frac{d}{dx}F_{u'}=0$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{2u(x)u(0)^2-2u(0)\big(u(x)^2+u'(x)^2\big)}{u(0)^4} - \frac{d}{dx}\bigg\{\frac{2u'(x)}{u(0)^2}\bigg\}=0,$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{2\big(u(x)u(0)-(u(x)^2+u'(x)^2)\big)}{u(0)^3}-\frac{2u''(x)u(0)}{u(0)^3}=0,$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{2}{u(0)^3}\bigg[u(0)\big(u(x)-u''(x)\big)-\big(u(x)^2+u'(x)^2\big)\bigg]=0.$$

But I can't work out what to do from here.

Does anybody know if this is even along the right lines? Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you wish to find
$$
C=\inf\left\{\frac{\int_0^1\left[u^2(x)+u'^2(x)\right]{\rm d}x}{u^2(0)}:u\in C(\left[0,1\right])\cap C^1(\left(0,1\right))\right\}.
$$
Note that
$$
\frac{\int_0^1\left[u^2(x)+u'^2(x)\right]{\rm d}x}{u^2(0)}=\int_0^1\left[\left(\frac{u(x)}{u(0)}\right)^2+\left(\frac{u(x)}{u(0)}\right)'^2\right]{\rm d}x.
$$
Thus your target is equivalent to figure out
$$
C=\inf\left\{\int_0^1\left[v^2(x)+v'^2(x)\right]{\rm d}x:v\in C(\left[0,1\right])\cap C^1(\left(0,1\right)),v(0)=1\right\}.
$$
The functional derivative yields the governing equation
$$
v''(x)=v(x),
$$
with the variational boundary condition
$$
v'(1)=0.
$$
In addition, we also have the imposed boundary condition
$$
v(0)=1.
$$
These lead to a unique solution for $v$, i.e.,
$$
w(x)=\frac{e^x+e^{2-x}}{1+e^2}.
$$
Thanks to this solution, the desired optimal $C$ follows immediately, i.e.,
$$
C=\int_0^1\left[w^2(x)+w'^2(x)\right]{\rm d}x=1-\frac{2}{1+e^2}\approx 0.7616.
$$

Comment: Why is $v'(1) = 0$?

Comment: @Makogan: This is a boundary condition obtained by minimizing the functional.