# Finding a constant such that the following integral inequality holds

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, optimization, calculus-of-variations

I am tasked to find a constant $c>0$ such that for all $C^1$ functions in $(0, 1)$ this variational problem is true:

$$cu(0)^2 \leq \int^1_0 u'^2 + u^2 dt$$

My instinct told me to calculate the minimizer of that funcitonal, and I got that it must be of the form $c_1e^t + c_2e^{-t} = \bar{u}$, where $\bar{u}$ is the minimizer.

Then we can compute the minimum quite easily in the general case and get that $c_1(e^{2} - 1)$ is a  lower bound for the functional.

But all this allows me to state is that:

$$c_1(e^{2} - 1) \leq \int^1_0 u'^2 + u^2 dt$$

I am not sure ow to introduce the $u(0)$ term.

Comment: If your goal is to find any $c$, then my answer suffices; if you want to find the best constant, this is done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2766719/optimal-constant-for-a-functional-inequality).

Comment: Do you think that it's a duplicate? If yes, we can close it as a duplicate and I will delete my answer.

Comment: It is a duplicate, do you know in that answer why $v'(0) = 1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the fundamental theorem of calculus,

$$u (0) =  -\int_0^t u'(s)ds + u(t) ,$$
thus by Holder inequality,
\begin{align}
 u^2(0) &\le 2\left( \int_0^t u'(s)\right)^2 ds + 2u^2(t) \\
& \le 2\left(\int_0^t 1 ^2 ds \int_0^t u'^2(s) ds\right) ds + 2u^2(t) \\
&\le 2\int_0^1 u'^2(s) ds+2 u^2(t) 
\end{align}

Integrating with respect to $t$ from $0$ to $1$,

$$u^2(0) \le 2\int_0^1 u'^2(s)+2 \int_0^1 u^2(t)dt.$$